# Unsafe IO Or: Haskeline and Directories

Tags: haskell, io-monad, haskeline

**DISCLAIMER: I am somewhat new to Haskell.**

I am writing an interpreter, or, in this context, a REPL. For that purpose I am using haskeline, which is nice for REPLs. It has the capability of storing the command line history within a file, which is also nice.

One problem I came across while working with it, though, is that it does not seem to expand "~" to the home directory, which means that I have to retrieve the home directory manually.

I could do it like this (and currently do):

```
-- | returns a fresh settings variable
addSettings :: Env -> Settings IO
addSettings env = Settings { historyFile = Just getDir
                           , complete = completeWord Nothing " \t" $
                                        return . completionSearch env
                           , autoAddHistory = True
                           }
    where
        getDir :: FilePath
        getDir = unsafePerformIO getHomeDirectory ++ "/.zepto_history"
```

But that uses `unsafePerformIO`, which makes me cringe. Do you know of a good and clean workaround that does not involve rewriting the whole function? This can be a `haskeline` feature I do not know of or something I just did not see.

Telling me there is no way around rewriting and rethinking it all is fine, too.

**EDIT:**

I know `unsafePerformIO` is bad, that's why it makes me cringe. If you are new to Haskell and reading this question right now: Just pretend it is not there.

Comment: Could you not just generate the settings inside `IO`, as in `addSettings env = do { homeDir <- getHomeDirectory; return $ Settings { historyFile = Just (homeDir ++ "/.zepto_historY"), ... }`?  Since you're new to Haskell I'll give the typical warning of **DON'T USE `unsafePerformIO`!** It's unsafe (obviously) and can lead to very unexpected behavior.  It's not part of the Haskell language even, it's part of the GHC implementation and is useful mainly when interfacing with C libraries or when working with low level features.

Comment: I know that. That's why it makes me cringe.

Comment: **Never ever perform unsafe IO!** Learn about the IO monad: http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output

Comment: Just trying to drive the point home.  There is almost always an alternative, such as the one i suggested above.  Would that approach work for you?

Comment: I just tried it out. I had to rewrite a few minor things, but it worked. Thanks, such a simple solution; I just had this: "You could have found that out yourself" moment which always comes with good answers. Would you add the answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: @AJFarmar: I agree, but for the record, this doesn't mean it's a good idea to write everything in the `IO` monad. On the contrary, first consideration should be avoiding IO that isn't really necessary at all.

Comment: In general unsafe IO is a bad idea, but `unsafePerformIO getHomeDirectory` is pretty safe (unless your operating system likes to change your home directory while your process is still running)

Comment: I thought as much, but I wanted to avoid it if possible, because it is bad practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better approach would be to generate the `Settings` object inside `IO`, instead of the other way around, so to speak:

```
addSettings :: Env -> IO (Settings IO)
addSettings = do
    getDir <- fmap (++ "/.zepto_history") getHomeDirectory
    return $ Settings
        { historyFile = Just getDir
        , complete = completeWord Nothing " \t" $ return . completionSearch env
        , autoAddHistory = True
        }
```

This will no doubt require some changes in your current software, but this would be considered the "right" way to go about this.